# Assistance understanding some notation in Navier-Stokes equations

Tags: notation, fluid-dynamics

A computational fluid dynamics example solves the equations below. I'm trying to learn the software and a bit of fluid dynamics concurrently. I believe that this is an integral form of the Navier-Stokes equation, conserving quantities within fixed volume elements.

My skills understanding notation are "underdeveloped".

- In the first integral, what is the meaning of the colon?
- after the comma, what is the "upside-down A"-like symbol? Do I read that as *for all $\mathbf{v}$*?

From SfePy example [navier_stokes/navier_stokes2d.py](http://sfepy.org/doc-devel/examples/navier_stokes/navier_stokes2d.html):

> [image: Navier-Stokes integral]

Comment: Regarding the second question: the so-called quantifier $\forall$ (in Tex written es `\forall`) indeed is read as "for all **v**".

Comment: Regarding the first question: simply searching for *"colon meaing vector calculus"* directs me to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348739/double-dot-product-vs-double-inner-product) calling this notation "double dot product" (something I haven't encountered yet). Without further context it cannot be said to be the right one here.

Comment: @mrtaurho part way down first page and *bottom of page 13* here https://www.materials.uoc.gr/el/grad/courses/METY101/FLUID_DYNAMICS_CRETE.pdf and addressed in [notation in navier stokes equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1468995/284619) I think you've solved it.

Comment: Is there anything I could improve which prevents you from accepting my answer? Please, feel free to say!

Comment: @mrtaurho usually I wait a few days to 1) see if other answers are added, 2) see how people respond to current answers (votes, comments) and 3) acceptance bumps the question back to the active queue, providing a little extra visibility and therefore one more opportunity for further feedback.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't meant to bother you.

Comment: @mrtaurho no bother at all! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making my own comments an answer.

Concerning the first question: as I already mentioned the notation $\textbf A:\textbf B$ most likely refers to the [Double Dot Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics#Double-dot_product). What exactly happens here (more precise what is multplied here) is, at least to me, not entirely clear since I am not that experienced within this field of mathematics and especially I have never encountered the Double Dot Product, as representative of products of dyadics, before. However, within the [Wikipedia article of the Navier Stokes equations, subsection Compressible Flow (and it's used within Incompressible Flow too)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations#Compressible_flow) it is also used as Double Dot Product from were I can conclude that is then which it refers to here. Additionally, [the arcticle](https://www.materials.uoc.gr/el/grad/courses/METY101/FLUID_DYNAMICS_CRETE.pdf) you linked calls it "double dot".

Concerning the second question: this one is one of the two commonly used [quantifiers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Quantifier.html). On the one hand we got the *exitential quantifier* $\exists$ (`\exists` in Tex, read as "there exists...") and one the other hand the *universal quantifier* $\forall$ (`\forall` in Tex, read as "for all..."). Here we read $\forall\underline v$ as "for all vectors $v$" and similiar $\forall q$ as "for all scalars $q$" (the information of vectors and scalars is not included within the quantifiers but within the remaining notation).